# Where to fix character encoding issues: before db insertion

Tags: sql-server, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm working web project with a mssql backend, not in my control except for tapping it. 
A lot of the data is littered with garbage characters in place of tradmarks, quotes, register symbols and quotes.

The html I'm rendering in is set to utf-8.

Is this encoding problem something that should be taken care of on the insertion of the data into the db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem should be taken care of where it's wrong. If you try to take care of it somewhere else, then you don't fix the problem, you only try to recover lost data.

When you handle encoded text, you have to do it correctly all the way. If you encode it or decode it incorrectly at one point in the process, you can't reliably fix it at any other point.

You have to find out where the text gets encoded or decoded incorrectly by examining what's happening to the data, and apply the fix there.

Comment: so if I understand you, the data should be encoded correctly on insertion into the db. In this case UTF-8 as that seems to be the choice for html? I know there is some wackiness going on to get this data into the db on the backend, and the person doing it is not at all familiar with the web, although he's in charge of the design of the of the db

Comment: @Ronn: The data should be encoded or decoded according to what's appropriate for each step. When storing the data in the database it's irrelevant that it later on will be displayed on a web page, so the only concern is that it should be stored properly in the database. When you read it from the database you should prepare the text for being displayed on the web page, which may include encoding it as utf-8, but may also include html encoding depending on where it's used in the html code.

Comment: ok. "should be stored properly in the database" what does that mean exactly here? The fact that I'm encountering all of the garbage characters a result of it not being properly stored in the db?

Comment: @Ronn: It means that you either has to save the text as unicode (nvarchar), or using a character set that supports the special characters, and send the data to the database in the same format. If the characters are incorrect when you look at the database content in Management Studio, then it's not correctly saved.